# find patern and append and replace it in file

Tags: sed

I want to search for a pattern and append to that in a file.

To be precise here is an example of my pattern and there are hundreds in a file.

```
         <size>30</size> needs to be replaced with <size>30,-1</size>
```

But the number in place of 30 is a variable (it can be any number from 0-99)

I am new to sed but I have used sed with known patterns but dont know how to modify when there is a variable in the pattern.

also I saw a sample where the code is placed in .sed file

```
      for example: sed replace.sed datafile.xyz > new.xyz
```

how do I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed` you can store part of the matched text with parentheses and include it in the replacement:

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4

So, for example:

```
sed 's:<size>\([0-9][0-9]*\)</size>:<size>\1,-1</size>:g' ...
```

Comment: What if u wanna match from one line but substitute on another?

Answer (score 0):

... and about reading sed commands from a file:

```
s:<size>\([0-9][0-9]*\)</size>:<size>\1,-1</size>:g
```

and call it:

```
sed -f commands.sed file.html
```

If you have multiple commands, put each in its own line.

Answer (score 0):

I know this hasn't been tagged under `perl` so feel free to ignore it. But with **`perl's positive look-ahead`** and **`look-behind`** you can do something like this -

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\<size\>)([0-9]{2})(?=\<\/size\>)/$1,-1/' yourfile
```